# Is there a way to handle spaces in secret dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

What I am trying to realize is to have a secret dictionary.
But this code can’t handle spaces in sentences. Hope you can help me out here, because in the dictionary {‘’:’’} doesn’t work.

```
import random

wordListRandom = {'a': 'u', 'b': 's', 'c': 'g', 'd': 'e', 'e': 'l', 'f': 'a', 'g': 'f', 'h': 'r', 'i': 'i', 'j': 'q', 'k': 'f', 'l': 'h', 'm': 'g', 'n': 'n', 'o': 'c', 'p': 'o', 'q': 'g', 'r': 'k', 's': 'x', 't': 'd', 'u': 'q', 'v': 'b', 'w': 'n', 'x': 'h', 'y': 'x', 'z': 'y'}

wordList1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j','k','l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't','u','v','w', 'x', 'y', 'z',]

#secretList = {k:random.choice(wordList1) for k in wordList1}
#print(secretList)

secretQuestion = input("Write your text: "))
secretAnswer = ''
for i in secretQuestion:
    secretAnswer = secretAnswer + wordListRandom[i]
print(secretAnswer)
```

Comment: you can use the `string` module and import from there the `ascii_lowercase` instead making own list of letters

Comment: about these spaces, can you map space to something ? like this `wordListRandom[' '] = ' '` or just use `defaultdict` from `collections` and assign some default value for every missing key.

Comment: Hi @Take_Care_ thanks for your reply. The ascii_lowercase works great. Also I used the setdefault feature and this works.